# Axios request failed with status code 406

Tags: react-native, axios, form-data

I tried to submit data from react native multi step form with axios to a symfony backend with api platform.

I used axios to handle request like this :

```
    const contactProject = new FormData()
    contactProject.append('propertyType', defaultpropretyType)
```

and then i send the object with axios post to api like this :

```
axios
      .post(`${API.URL}/contact_projects`, contactProject, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${this.props.token}`,
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log('LA REPONSE DE POST CONTACT PROJECT')
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('ERROR POST CONTACT PROJECT')
        console.log(contactProject)
        console.log(error)
      })
```

The form data object that i'm sending to api is like this :

```
FormData {
  "_parts": Array [
    Array [
      "propertyType",
      "maison",
    ],
    Array [
      "budget",
      "0",
    ],
    Array [
      "surface",
      5,
    ],
    Array [
      "nbRooms",
      5,
    ],
    Array [
      "tradeOperationType",
      "/trade_operation_types/1",
    ],
  ],
}
```

That's why i'm getting 406 error, i need a pure json object to send so how can i convert the FormData to json ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just send it.
For your case:

```
const contactProject={
propertyType: defaultpropretyType,
...
}
axios
      .post(`${API.URL}/contact_projects`, contactProject, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${this.props.token}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      })
```

Comment: When should i use a form data ?  i'm confused cauz i used form data form the login component and it works

Comment: The server side determine which type to accept. Form data is the old manner, in other words, which is the "native" data type of web, but now we often use JSON, directly, when we use JSON directly, we should add request header content-type: application/json

Comment: Sorry, I edited the answer, changed the content-type.